# Using forEach in an array to find an object and change it's value in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, foreach

I have a statement like so:

```
private updateVariable(anId:number): void {

    this.model.forEach(q => 
        {
            q.anId === anId && (q.isUpdated = !q.isUpdated)
        });
```

The model is defined as:

```
private model:Array<IMyData> = [];
```

Also IMyData is defined with this:

```
export interface IMyData{
    anId:number;
    isUpdated:boolean;
}
```

The goal is to iterate over the data to find the matching anId and:

change isUpdated from:

```
null and false to true
```

and from:

```
true to false
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error with the above statement?

Comment: Why do you need to use forEach when you can do it using filter?

Comment: @KiranShakya that's not what the code is doing.

Comment: If you don't mind `null` being changed to `false`, you could just write `q.isUpdated = q.isUpdated ^ (q.anId === anId)`

Comment: This code doesn't look bad, what's wrong with it? You didn't say what the problem is

Comment: @Nick first bitwise operator are not recommended by most linters. Maybe `q.isUpadted !== (q.anId === anId)`. Second, though this would work, in my opinion `if (q.anId === anId) { q.isUpdated = !q.isUpdated }` is more readable.

Comment: The is a bug but i am going to edit the fix now. I need null and false to true and true to false.

Comment: @cdub could you please elaborate. From what I see, your code should work. But do you have any special input values? What can `isUpdated` and `anId` hold?

Comment: yes it is working now. i wasn't sure if the null would turn into a true.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 1 line instead. Using Array's `.map()`

```
const anId = '123';

this.model = this.model.map(item => item.anId === anId ? {...item, isUpdated: !item.isUpdated} : item)

console.log(this.model);     // to check the array with it's updated data
```